# How do I make a form scroll down with mouse wheel instead of changing records in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, mousewheel

I have a longish form that scrolls vertically and also allows editing records. When I scroll with the mouse wheel, the form changes records instead of scrolling up and down to see more of the form. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Can't recreate your problem in Access 2007. Does your form navigation or record selection have an particular settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=890

If not that, then this:
 http://www.google.com/?q=Disable+mouse+scroll+MS+Access+for+traversing+records